# Given two strings, how do I find number of reoccurences of one in another?

Tags: string, matlab

For example, `s1='abc'`, `s2='kokoabckokabckoab'`.
Output should be `3`. (number of times s1 appears in s2).

Not allowed to use `for` or `strfind`. *Can only use `reshape`,`repmat`,`size`*.

I thought of reshaping s2, so it would contain all of the possible strings of 3s:

> ### s2 =
>
> kok
>
> oko
>
> koa
>
> oab
>
> .... etc

But I'm having troubles from here..

Comment: Just to be sure: do you have a 'c' missing at the very end of s2 above? (So that the output is 3)

Comment: what about `ismember`?

Comment: Can we use `sum`?  I can determine a solution, but it would also need `sum`.  BTW, your MATLAB tutor still sucks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have your matrix reshaped into the format you have in your post, you can replicate `s1` and stack the string such that it has as many rows as there are in the reshaped `s2` matrix, then do an equality operator.  Rows that consist of all 1s means that we have found a match and so you would simply search for those rows where the total sum is equal to the total length of `s1`.  Referring [back to my post on dividing up a string into overlapping substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208647/separating-a-string-for-different-substrings), we can decompose your string into what you have posted in your question like so:

```
%// Define s1 and s2 here
s1 = 'abc';
len = length(s1);
s2 = 'kokoabckokabckoab'; 

%// Hankel starts here
c = (1 : len).'; 
r = (len : length(s2)).';
nr = length(r);
nc = length(c);

x = [ c; r((2:nr)') ];          %-- build vector of user data

cidx = (1:nc)';
ridx = 0:(nr-1);
H = cidx(:,ones(nr,1)) + ridx(ones(nc,1),:);  % Hankel subscripts
ind = x(H);                            % actual data
%// End Hankel script

%// Now get our data
subseqs = s2(ind.');

%// Case where string length is 1
if len == 1
    subseqs = subseqs.';
end
```

---

`subseqs` contains the matrix of overlapping characters that you have alluded to in your post.  You've noticed a small bug where if the length of the string is 1, then the algorithm won't work.  You need to make sure that the reshaped substring matrix consists of a single **column** vector.  If we ran the above code without checking the length of `s1`, we would get a row vector, and so simply transpose the result if this is the case.

Now, simply replicate `s1` for as many times as we have rows in `subseqs` so that all of these strings get stacked into a 2D matrix.  After, do an equality operator.

```
eqs = subseqs == repmat(s1, size(subseqs,1), 1);
```

Now, find the column-wise sum and see which elements are equal to the length of your string.  This will produce a single column vector where `1` indicates that we have found a match, and zero otherwise:

```
sum(eqs, 2) == len

ans =

     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
```

Finally, to add up **how many times** the substring matched, you just have to add up all elements in this vector:

```
out = sum(sum(eqs, 2) == len)

out = 

2
```

---

As such, we have **two** instances where `abc` is found in your string.

Comment: It's very good, since you have made an answer out of nothing! `ismember` makes it easier but it's probably not allowed. +1

Comment: What happens if the length of s1 is 1?

Comment: @Osh24 - Good point.  I need to make sure that `subseqs` is a column vector if that's the case.  Once you do this, the algorithm will work.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! Can you explain the Hankel formation? H = cidx(:,ones(nr,1)) + ridx(ones(nc,1),:); What matrix is created from cidx(:ones(n1,1)) --> It's a bit confusing because of the ones array :\

Comment: `cidx(:,ones(nr1,1));` is basically `repmat(cidx,1,nr1);`  It replicates `cidx` assuming it is a column vector for `nr1` times.

Comment: @rayryeng Clear now! Thanks :)

Comment: @Osh24 - My pleasure :) Same logic can be applied with `ridx`.  It replicates the rows.  If you print out those matrices by themselves, you'll see that adding them both together will give you the indices that will give the interleaved substrings per column.

Comment: I like this solution because it is valid for any string size. +1

Comment: @rayryeng - To make the answer exactly to the OPs specification we should substitute `length(.)` by `size(.(:),1)`, `ones(...)` by `repmat(1,...)` and of course get rid of the sum. ;-)
`matches = (eqs*repmat(1,len,1)==len); 
tmp = 1:size(matches,1); 
tmp(~matches) = []; 
out = size(tmp(:),1);`

Comment: @knedlsepp - Thanks for your suggestion.  I'll keep what I have because it's what I originally wrote, and it's what I understand the problem to be.  Also, as the OP has accepted the answer, I think I'm good :)

Comment: Just wanted to point out the absurdity of only being allowed to use *`reshape`, `repmat` and `size`*. ;-)

Comment: @knedlsepp - OH LOL.  The OP has accepted the answer, so I think using `sum` and `length` are ok... I didn't receive any complaints.  Yes. Using just those functions is a bit ridiculous.  You should have seen this question by the OP as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006489/comparing-arrays-of-different-sizes-without-any-loop - The OP kept changing the requirements for this question - adding in functions we could not use.  I eventually got fed up and publicly announced my disdain for the question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another one,

```
s1='abc'; 
s2='bkcokbacaabcsoabckokabckoabc';

[a,b] = ismember(s2,s1);
b = [0 0 b 0 0];
a1=circshift(b,[0 -1]);
a2=circshift(b,[0 -2]);
sum((b==1)&(a1==2)&(a2==3))
```

It gives `3` for your input and `4` for my example, and it seems to work well if `ismember` is okey.

Comment: If `ismember` and `circshift` is allowed, this is what I would have done too :) +1.

Comment: Nice approach. My only complaint would be that the code is valid only for a fixed size of `s1` (3 in this case). +1

Answer (score 3):

Just for the fun of it: this can be done with [`nlfilter`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/nlfilter.html) from the Image Processing Toolbox (I just discovered this function today and am eager to apply it!):

```
ds1 = double(s1);
ds2 = double(s2);
result = sum(nlfilter(ds2, [1 numel(ds1)], @(x) all(x==ds1)));
```

Comment: Yes you are right my answer does have that drawback, and I didn't realize it, this is very nice BTW +1,

Comment: OH, you found it :).  I've used this for a bunch of my answers too.  Nice!

Comment: I saw it today in an answer by Divakar. Pity that I missed it in your answers! However, now that I've used the function for the first time, I see it's probably a slow function. On my Matlab version it even (brefly) displays a waitbar

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for the edit! I guess the emotion of my first time with `nlfilter` clouded my vision :-D

Comment: @LuisMendo - There are some shortcuts depending on how you want to use `nlfilter`.  For example, if you want to find the local maximum of image pixel neighbourhoods, use `imdilate` and for the local minimum, use `imerode`.  The morphology routines are much more efficient than `nlfilter`, as `nlfilter` is for more general non-linear filtering while the morphology filters are tuned for a specific task.  Either way, cool to see you use it!

Comment: @rayryeng I see. I don't do image processing very often. Cool things one learns here!