# Converting an image double to logical using a 5x5 window. MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a double image and my aim is to convert it to logical. I want to create 5x5 window and put it on each pixel in the image. Then, I calculate the average of these 25 pixels. If the center pixel value is greater then the average value, it will be 1. Otherwise 0.

How can I do that?

P.S. I don't want to do that this way:

```
IM[i - 2, j - 2]
IM[i - 1, j - 2]
IM[i, j - 2]
IM[i + 1, j - 2]
IM[i + 2, j - 2]
      .
      .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several approaches (running time is probably in decreasing order):

1. With [`nlfilter`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/nlfilter.html):

   ```
   result = nlfilter(im, [5 5], @(x) x(3,3)>mean(x(:)));
   ```
2. With [`blockproc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html):

   ```
   result = blockproc(im, [1 1], @(x) x.data(3,3)>mean(x.data(:)), ...
       'Bordersize', [2 2], 'Trimborder', 0);
   ```

   Note that with `blockproc` we need to specify blocks of size 1x1 (so that the block "moves" from pixel to pixel in each direction), border of size 2 in eacch direction around wach pixel (to get 5x5 blocks), and prevent the function result from being trimned, because the result is just 1 value.
3. With [`conv2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html):

   ```
   result = im > conv2(im, ones(5,5)/25, 'same');
   ```

Comment: Finally using it! Nice.

Comment: Yep! My second answer with `nlfilter` :-D

Comment: Which one's the first?

Comment: It's [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27325226/2586922). Admittedly a not very natural use of `nlfilter`

Comment: All of them work quite good but I have a question. I don't understand the 3rd method. You create a 5*5 matrix full of ones but I can't understand how this matrix can be our window?

Comment: hehe, nice to see other `nfilter`users :-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/22818561/2777181

Comment: @sigara The 3rd method uses 2D-[convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). It applies a mask (the 5x5 constant matrix) around each pixel and sums the product of pixel values times mask. The mask values are chosen such that the convolution result is the mean

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, it seems like a outlier method. The code below may be what you wanted:

```
mask   = 0.04 * ones(5); mask(3, 3) = 0; % // mask is for average the double image
avgIm  = filter2(mask, imd); % // imd is your double image.
output = imd > avgIm;
```

Comment: In this code I am calculating average value of all neighbour (24 pixel except current pixel). You can comment out the part "mask(3, 3) = 0;"